# How to link local branches to corresponding remote branches and avoid/limit unwanted local push to different branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-push, git-pull

Imagine this basic scenario:

- I have 4 local branches named dev-brA dev-brB prod-brA prod-brB
- I also have 2 remote branches origin/brA origin/brB

What I would like to obtain is that :
 -  local prod-brA may push to origin/brA and not to origin/brB, and  origin/brA would be the default for push pull action for prod-brA
 - local prod-brB may push to origin/brA and not to origin/brA, and  origin/brB would be the default for push pull action for prod-brB

**Note**: Remotes are not on github but on bare shared repo

In other words I don't want that local<->remote push pull action would not cross over. If I want to mix A with B i would do it only locally by merging.

How would you set up the .git/config file to set this up?

Many thanks for

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default tracking branch with:

```
$ git branch -u origin/brA prod-brA
```

This sets the default remote branch (origin/brA) that will be used when push/pull operations are used with the given local branch (prod-brA).

I don't think there's any way to prevent one branch from pushing to another with Git (perhaps these rules can be set up on your repository host, if you have one) but if you set up your remote tracking branches correctly, you would not be able to push/pull to/from the wrong repository accidentally, which I assume is what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Thanks. Thats ok for the default push/pull. How do you recommend to setup the remote shared repository in order to prevent unauthorized branches to push to origin/master for example? Is the only way to obtain this by setting up users/permissions?

Comment: I don't understand, are you wanting to prevent certain users from pushing to origin/master? Or prevent someone from pushing a *different* branch? If it's the latter, why is this a problem? You should only be pushing your local master branch to origin/master, not any other.